# Postgres: Getting json object from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, node-postgres

I want to return `{id: 'single-entry'}` instead of `[{Id:'single-entry'}]`

I'm running `PostgreSQL v11.5`

I looked at many different examples online, but array with one row in it won't turn into a json object.

From this query:

```sql
SELECT row_to_json(row)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        json_agg(json_build_object('name', tr."name", 'id', r."remixTrackId")) 
        FILTER (WHERE tr."id" IS NOT NULL)
        AS remixes
    FROM "Tracks" t
        LEFT JOIN "Remixes" r ON r."originalTrackId" = t."id"
        LEFT JOIN "Tracks" tr ON tr."id" = r."remixTrackId"
    WHERE t."id" = '${trackId}'
    GROUP BY t."id"
) row;
```

What i would expect:

```
{
  "id": "track-id2",
  "name": "My track 2",
  "dateModified": "2019-11-09T21:41:30.482634",
  "channels": {
    "some": "json"
  },
  "userId": 1,
  "remixes": null
}
```

What i get:

```
[
  {
    "row_to_json": {
      "id": "track-id2",
      "name": "My track 2",
      "dateModified": "2019-11-09T21:41:30.482634",
      "channels": {
        "some": "json"
      },
      "userId": 1,
      "remixes": null
    }
  }
]
```

DB connection and query looks like this.
I'm using Node and Heroku where Postgres is running

This is a more complete snippet of how i execute the query:

```js
const pg = require('pg')
const config = {
    user: 'xxx',
    database: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    port: 5432,
    ssl: true
};
const pool = new pg.Pool({ 
    connectionString: `postgres://${config.user}:${config.password}@xxx.amazonaws.com:5432/${config.database}`,
    ...config
})

app.get('/api/postgres/get-track', function(request, response) {
    const trackId = R.path(['query','id'], request)
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            response.send("Could not connect to DB: " + err)
        } else {
            client.query(`
            SELECT row_to_json(row)
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    t.*,
                    json_agg(json_build_object('name', tr."name", 'id', r."remixTrackId")) 
                    FILTER (WHERE tr."id" IS NOT NULL)
                    AS remixes
                FROM "Tracks" t
                    LEFT JOIN "Remixes" r ON r."originalTrackId" = t."id"
                    LEFT JOIN "Tracks" tr ON tr."id" = r."remixTrackId"
                WHERE t."id" = '${trackId}'
                GROUP BY t."id"
            ) row;
            `, function(err, result) {
                done()
                if(err) return response.send(err)
                response.send(result.rows);
            })
        }
    }) 
})
```

Please help me point out what i'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `json_agg` if you don't want an array?

Comment: @Bergi I use that to create an array for the "remixes" field, that's needed.
The problem is that the whole entry ends up being within an array.

If i remove the `json_agg` and the whole "remixes" field then it's still an array.

It just happens that this particular ID which i queried didn't have any remixes and then i return null instead of an array.

It could look like this as well:

Comment: Ah, now I see your problem. The outer array is created by your db driver, which doesn't know that the query returns only a single result - it might hold multiple rows. Similarly, it outputs the object with the `row_to_json` key instead of the plain result object because it doesn't know there's only a single column - there might be others. Please show us the code that is executing this query.

Comment: To follow up on my comment, here is what it could look like if the entry has remixes:

```json
[
   {
      "row_to_json":{
         "id":"track-id",
         "name":"My track 1",
         "dateModified":"2019-11-09T21:41:30.379751",
         "channels":{
            "some":"json"
         },
         "userId":1,
         "remixes":[
            {
               "name":"My track 2",
               "id":"track-id2"
            },
            {
               "name":"My track 3",
               "id":"track-id3"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: @Bergi I can't, i can only post short snippets here.
But please provide more information about it so i can research it on my own.

Comment: Don't post the entire code, post only the relevant parts that have to do with this particular query and how you set up your database connection. You can remove the other snippets (which are not as important for the question) if you hit a code limit.

Comment: At least tag your question with the language and db library you are using for your application. I can't provide any more details than I already have without knowing those.

Comment: If you're using javascript, you're probably using node.js? Which library?

Comment: @Bergi I have provided what you asked for in the main post. Yes, it's node and Postgres is running on heroku.

Comment: @Bergi You pointed me in the right direction and i solved it. I just picked it out from the array with javascript and skipped `row_to_json` completely.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you solved it, but please [post the answer as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `json_agg()` function and add all columns in the SELECT list to the GROUP BY list within the subquery

```
SELECT row_to_json(row) as remixes
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
          t."id", t."name", t."dateModified",
          json_build_object('some', tr."some") AS channels,
          t."userId", null AS "remixes"
      FROM "Tracks" t
      LEFT JOIN "Remixes" r ON r."originalTrackId" = t."id"
      LEFT JOIN "Tracks" tr ON tr."id" = r."remixTrackId"
     WHERE t."id" = '${trackId}'
  GROUP BY t."id", t."name", t."userId", tr."some", t."dateModified"
) row
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the solution looks like this (with help from JS):

```js
const R = require('ramda')
const pg = require('pg')

app.get('/api/postgres/get-track', function(request, response) {
    const trackId = R.path(['query','id'], request)
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            response.send("Could not connect to DB: " + err)
        } else {
            client.query(`
                SELECT 
                    t.*,
                    json_agg(json_build_object('name', tr."name", 'id', r."remixTrackId")) 
                    FILTER (WHERE tr."id" IS NOT NULL)
                    AS remixes
                FROM "Tracks" t
                    LEFT JOIN "Remixes" r ON r."originalTrackId" = t."id"
                    LEFT JOIN "Tracks" tr ON tr."id" = r."remixTrackId"
                WHERE t."id" = '${trackId}'
                GROUP BY t."id";
            `, function(err, result) {
                done()
                if(err) return response.send(err)
                const foundTrack = R.head(result.rows)
                if(foundTrack) {
                    response.send(foundTrack)
                } else {
                    //Error response here
                }
            })
        }
    }) 
})
```